# c++ std::stack content will not be free when leaving function

Tags: c++, std

I think in function err_fun, the stack em will be free when leave err_fun(), so the content of em will be free in the same time, and why 
i can still get right answer in main function with stack st?

Thanks.

```
#include <stack>

stack<int> st;

void err_fun() {
    stack<int> em;
    st.swap( em );
}

int main() {
    err_fun();

    //... some operation with stack st.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes `em` will be destroyed, but `st` won't. They're independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of `em` will be copied over as that's what you asked for when you did [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/swap). Since `st` is global in scope it's not destroyed.

Comment: I thought that the swap method just move the content pointer. Is the swap method always copy the whole content to target content ? like copy em's content to st's content.

Comment: I linked to the documentation and it goes into extremely specific detail. If you want to know more, that's the place to go.